# Group a collection and take first 5 from each group

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection. I need to group the collection by "A" property. And I have to sort each group by"B" property. Then select first 5 from each group.

Can anyone suggest a LINQ query for this?

The way I tried is not working.

```
 (from item in Recipes
 orderby item.Rating descending
 group item by item.MainCategory).Take(5)
```

The query should return `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, myrecipetype>>`

Comment: You will need `GroupBy`, `OrderBy` and `Take` operators

Comment: The OP has demonstrated his attempt at trying this, I don't see what the problem is?

Comment: @DeeMac Look at when it was last edited and the times comments were left...

Comment: The original problems with this question seem to have been fixed.

Comment: Why so many down votes. Still I didn't get a good suggestion.

Comment: @gleng - according to the edit the code was there from the start. Maybe he edited in time for it to not show as an edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are taking first five groups. Instead you need to select first five items from each group:

```
from item in Recipes   
orderby item.Rating descending      
group item by item.MainCategory into g
select g.Take(5)
```

UPDATE:

```
from item in Recipes   
orderby item.Rating descending      
group item by item.MainCategory into g
select g.Take(5).GroupBy(item => item.MainCategory).First()
```

Comment: This will not return group.

Comment: @XAMLLover yes, this will return `IEnumerable<Recipe>` instead of group

Comment: @XAMLLover updated answer. But I can't get why you need `IGrouping` here.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: In your case, with sorting added (after the OP was updated):

```
Recipes.GroupBy(recipy => recipy.MainCategory)
       .Select(recipyGroup => recipyGroup.OrderBy(recipy => recipy.Rating)
                                         .Take(5))
```